# Can not assign 'text' to 'FlatButton'

Tags: dart, flutter

I wrote the below `StatefulWidget` but at this part:

```
new FlatButton(
    child: new Text(
    ...
   )
),
```

I got the below error:

> [dart] the argument type 'Text' can't be assigned to the parameter
>   type 'Row'.

[image]

The full code is:

```
part of awesome_library;

class ContentPage extends StatefulWidget {
  ContentPage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _ContentPageState createState() => new _ContentPageState();
}

class _ContentPageState extends State<ContentPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text(
              'Click the button below to navigate back to the home screen ',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
            new FlatButton(
              child: new Text(
                "ok",
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
              ),
              textColor: new Color(0xFF66BB6A),               
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/home'),
        ),
          ],
        ), 
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly to you get that error? In the IDE or at runtime? Can you please add a screenshot?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer at the IDE

Comment: I copy pasted your code. Started it. Worked.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I attached screen shoot, it is at VS Code at MacBook Air.

Comment: do you need to wrap your text and button widgets in some sort of row widget?

Comment: @floor I just need to write the text I want to be displayed in the button, the app work fine, and at Android Studio no errors, just got the error at VS Code!